# self adjoint differential operator.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, compact-operators, differential-operators

Is this reasoning is correct:

Let $R$ be a self adjoint differential operator, acting on $L^2(\Bbb{R}^{2d}), d\in \Bbb{N}^*$, such that  $R$ is  diagonalizable in an orthonormal basis $(\Phi_{\alpha,\beta})_{(\alpha,\beta)\in \Bbb{N}^{d}}$ with

$$   R \Phi_{\alpha,\beta}= (|\alpha|-|\beta|)\Phi_{\alpha,\beta}$$

where $\alpha=(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_d)$ and $|\alpha|=|\alpha_1|+\dots+|\alpha_d|$.

Let $m\in \Bbb{Z}$ . I want to show that if there is a sequence $(u_{n})$ (depends on $m$) $L^2(\Bbb{R}^{2d})$  and $R(u_n)\in L^2(\Bbb{R}^{2d})$ such that

1]- $u_{n}\overset{Weakly}{\longrightarrow} 0$ i.e., for $f\in L^2(\Bbb{R}^{2d})$ we have  $<f,u_{n}>\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.

2]- $\big(R-  m) u_{n} \big) \overset{L^2(\Bbb{R}^{2d})}{\longrightarrow} 0$  as $n\to\infty$.

3]- $||u_n||=1$ for all $n\in \Bbb{N}$.

Then $u_{n}=c\Phi_{\alpha,\beta}$ with $|c|=1$ and $\alpha-\beta=m$.

Here is my reasoning:

Since $u_{n}\in L^2(\Bbb{R}^{2d})$, then $u_{n}=\sum_{\alpha',\beta'} c^{n}_{\alpha',\beta'}\Phi_{\alpha',\beta'}$ (The convergence of this series being in $L^2(\Bbb{R}^{2d})$) .

So $$\big(R-  m) u_{n} =\sum_{\alpha',\beta'}  c^{n}_{\alpha',\beta'}\big((|\alpha'|-|\beta'|) - m\big)  \Phi_{\alpha',\beta'}$$

(because $   R \Phi_{\alpha',\beta'}= (|\alpha'|-|\beta'|)\Phi_{\alpha',\beta'}$   et $(\sum g_k)'= (\sum (g_k)')$.

Hence $$||\big(R-  m) u_{n}||^2=\sum_{\alpha',\beta'} \Big|c^{n}_{\alpha',\beta'}\big((|\alpha'|-|\beta'|) - m \big) \Big|^2$$.

Now by  hypothesis $1$, for $f=\Phi_{\alpha',\beta'}$ (Here, we point out that $u_n$ depends on  $ m=|\alpha|-|\beta|$, so it is necessary that $(\alpha',\beta')\not=(\alpha,\beta)$).

Therefore :$$<u_{n},\Phi_{\alpha',\beta'}>=c^{n}_{\alpha',\beta'} \to 0$$

as $n\to\infty$.

But $||u_{n}||^2=\sum_{\alpha',\beta'}| c^{n}_{\alpha',\beta'}|^2=1$

I take  $n\to\infty$ for both members, and consequently necessarily we get:

$|c^{n}_{\alpha,\beta}|=1$

$ c^{n}_{\alpha',\beta'}=0$ avec $(\alpha',\beta')\not=(\alpha,\beta)$.

Finaly: $u_{n}=c\Phi_{\alpha,\beta}$ with $|c|=1$ and $\alpha-\beta=m$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The conclusion you're trying to arrive at (that $u_{\alpha,\beta} = c\Phi_{\alpha,\beta}$) can't literally be true because one can change finitely many of the functions $u_{\alpha,\beta}$ without affecting the first two hypotheses.  Perhaps you mean something else, or I am misunderstanding?

Comment: In fact, i correct it, see above

Comment: It seems that your new formulation has the same problem.  One can change $u_i$ to be arbitrary unit vectors in for $1\leq n\leq 100$ and not affect the hypotheses (1-3).  Perhaps you want to prove that there is a sequence $(\alpha_n,\beta_n)$ such that  $\|u_n - \Phi_{\alpha_n,\beta_n}\|\to 0$?

Comment: The explicit formula for $R$ is given by $\sum^{d}_{j=1}(x_{j} \frac{\partial}{\partial y_{j}}-y_{j} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_{j}})$. For $U_n=\Phi^{\lambda}_{\alpha,0}$ avec $n=|\alpha|$, we have  1]- $u_{n}\overset{Weakly}{\longrightarrow} 0$.

2]- $\big(R-  m) u_{n} \big) \overset{L^2(\Bbb{R}^{2d})}{\longrightarrow} 0$  as $n\to\infty$.

3]- $||u_n||=1$ for all $n\in \Bbb{N}$.

.

Comment: My question is if there is a sequence $u_n$ such that 1]- $u_{n}\overset{Weakly}{\longrightarrow} 0$ 

2]- $\big(R-  m) u_{n} \big) \overset{L^2(\Bbb{R}^{2d})}{\longrightarrow} 0$  as $n\to\infty$.

3]- $||u_n||=1$ for all $n\in \Bbb{N}$.

 Can we say $u_{n}=c\Phi_{\alpha,\beta}$ with $|c|=1$ .